# react navigation linking routes and deploying to vercel using expo

Tags: expo, react-navigation, vercel

I am adding url links to my expo app. It works during testing, but not after I deploy to Vercel.

This is the linking definition in my App.js:

```
const linking = {
  config: {
    screens: {
      Signin: "Splash",
      HomeStack: "Home",
    },
  },
};
```

This is the vercel.json file that I added to the root of my frontend directory, following with the expo instructions:

```
{
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "framework": null,
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

When I run the web build, and then use the vercel command to get a preview link `https://my-example.vercel.app`, I get

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: iad1:iad1::xjrzh-1690919144400-782695cc6820
```

I've tried many different configurations for the vercel.json file, including adding `Splash/Welcome`, etc to the rewrites. What am I missing here?

Edit: I also tried adding a prefix and expo-linking api

```
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

const linking = {
  prefixes: [Linking.createURL("/")],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Signin: "Splash",
      HomeStack: "Home",
    },
  },
};
```

Still getting 404 error.